# Ideals of Lie-algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am wondering whether the following claim is true:

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra and $V$ some vector subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$.

**Claim:** $V$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ if and only if $V$ is invariant under $\mathrm{Ad} \colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$, i.e. for all $g \in G$

$$ \mathrm{Ad}_g(V) \subseteq V $$

It is clear to me, that $V$ has to be invariant under $\mathrm{ad} \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathrm{End}(\mathfrak{g})$, since $\mathrm{ad}_X(Y)= [X,Y]$, but I struggle to proof this for $\mathrm{Ad}$. It may be that the claim only holds for semisimple Lie algebras, but I am not sure about that.

Any help or references are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I love this question because it feels so obviously true but indeed the proof is not obvious. Can we agree that, as you write, $V$ being an ideal is equivalent to $V$ being ad-invariant and that being ad-invariant follows quickly from being Ad-invariant, but that the converse (does being $ad$-invariant imply being Ad-invariant?) is the one that is not clear? In other words: can I interpret your question as 'Let $V$ be an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $g \in G$. Do we necessarily have that $Ad_g(V) \subset V$?

Comment: The answer to the last question is of course yes if $g$ is the exponential of some Lie algebra element. This holds for all $g$ if $G$ is compact and also, at the opposite end of the spectrum, if $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent, but for non-compact semi-simple groups we already have $g$ not of this form. I will think about it!

Comment: @Vincent, if $G$ is connected, there are no problems since in this case $\mathrm{Ad}_G$ is generated by $\mathrm{exp}(\mathrm{ad}_{\mathfrak{g}})$. The only case to study is the case of a non-connected Lie group.

Comment: Do you mean by "quickly" using $\mathrm{ad}_X(Y) = \frac{d}{d t} \mathrm{Ad}(e^{tX})(Y) \big|_{t=0}$?

Comment: Jbante: yes. @gniourf, ah yes, I didn't think of that. But it seems unlikely that the disconnectedness is going to be a problem. Generally we have that $G$ is the direct product of its identity component and a discrete group that is in its center and hence doesn't do much for Ad, right?

Comment: (ok, maybe that doesn't feel like quickly because it is a long and complicated formula, but in my head that is the definition of ad, so it is quick in the sense of 'not requiring many additional steps after writing down the definition.)

Comment: The assumption that $G$ is compact an connected is actually fine for me, since I want to apply the claim in a context, where this is always the case.
I do not have as much knowledge about the general lie theory, as I want to, to be honest :D (all of this came up while reading section 12 of chapter 5 in Bredons "Topology and Geometry")

Comment: Ok, so really all we need is a reference to the proof that for connected compact Lie groups the exponential map from the Lie algebra is surjective. Maybe it is in the book on compact Lie groups by Broecker and tom Dieck? I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this fact is at least mentioned in their book, I'll look it up. Thank you :)